# ios how to store time values in nsmutablearray and acessing objects from the array

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm trying to store and access randomly to times in array as objects but I'm getting a error:

Here is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *timer=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[timer addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:timeOne]];
[timer addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:timeTwo]];
 int timeIndex = arc4random() % [timer count];
double timeToBeUse=[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[timer objectAtIndex:timeIndex]];
```

on this line:

```
   double timeToBeUse=[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[timer objectAtIndex:timeIndex]];
```

I'm getting this error: "Sending id to parameter of incompatible type 'double'

any of you knows how to fix this or what would be the best way to approach this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: `arc4random() % [timer count]` -> `arc4random_uniform([timer count])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change that line to:

```
double timeToBeUse=[[timer objectAtIndex:timeIndex] doubleValue];
```

In your original version, you are trying to create a new NSNumber with a NSNumber instead of creating a double value.